# How do I most effectively compress my highly-unique columns?

Tags: apache-spark, compression, parquet, snappy

**I have a Spark DataFrame consisting of many double columns that are measurements, but I want a way of annotating each unique row by computing a hash of several other non-measurement columns. This hash results in garbled strings that are highly unique, and I've noticed my dataset size increases substantially when this column is present. How can I sort / lay out my data to decrease the overall dataset size?**

I know that the Snappy compression protocol used on my parquet files executes best upon runs of similar data, so I think a sort over the primary key could be useful, but I also can't coalesce() the entire dataset into a single file (it's hundreds of GB in total size before the primary key creation step).

My hashing function is SHA2(128) FYI.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a column that can be computed from the other columns, then simply omit that column before compression, and reconstruct it after decompression.